# 504 gateway time-out after long process in Flask app

Tags: python

How to handle with 504 gateway time-out from flask?. Is there anyway to increase timeout request or is there any better way for this?

I have flask POST method request and then doing some internal function processing. THe process take a long time >60s . And then I need to return the some value. However, I get 504 gateway timeout.

```
app=Flask(__name)

@app.route('/v1/config', methods=['POST'])
def post_income():
    content_type=request.headers.get('Content-Type')
    try:
        if (content_type=='application/json'):
            json_in=request.get_json()
            # function doing long process and return value
            value =' text variable from process'
            print(value)
            return value
```

This error happens:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>504 Gateway Time-out</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

The program works fine, print value as it is but 'return value' not show as expected instead it showed 504 gateway timeout

Thank you!

Comment: Flask doesn't have a built-in timeout. You must be running something in front of your Flask server as a reverse proxy.

Comment: I recommend you rather send a webpage telling that your Flask app successfully received the request (and to please wait), and let the client request the data some time after, using JavaScript.

Comment: @Selcuk and Biskweet: how to do it with Python

Comment: Hi Selcuk. what is 'something' you have referred to? Could you please detail more about this?

Comment: Is there anyone know the solution or reference for this? Thanks